# How to add keyUsage to certificate signing request in Golang

Tags: go, x509certificate, x509, pki

I need to create a PEM-encoded Certificate Signing Request (CSR) that specifies keyUsage certSign in a Golang application.

In Golang, function [x509.CreateCertificateRequest](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/x509#CreateCertificateRequest) helps with this, and it takes an [x509.CertificateRequest](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/x509#CertificateRequest) input parameter. Type CertificateRequest does not have a KeyUsage attribute, so I assume I must use its `Extensions` attribute to embed a KeyUsage in that CSR. That `Extensions` attribute is of type `[]pkix.Extension` and the pkix Go package does not really have much to help me build a KeyUsage extension.

KeyUsage is documented in [RFC5280 section 4.2.1.3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.3) as a BIT STRING with OBJECT IDENTIFIER id-ce 15. Would the following be the right way to create that KeyUsage? Is there no easier way that leverages the pkix or x509 Go packages and avoids doing my own bit serialization? Is my bit serialization even in compliance with that RFC, how can I test this?

```
asn1KeyUsage, err := asn1.Marshal(asn1.BitString{
        Bytes:     []byte{byte(x509.KeyUsageCertSign)},
        BitLength: 8,
    })
if err != nil { ... }

csrTemplate := x509.CertificateRequest{
        SignatureAlgorithm: ...,
        PublicKeyAlgorithm: ...,
        PublicKey:          ...,
        Subject:            ...,
        ExtraExtensions: []pkix.Extension{
            {
                Id:       asn1.ObjectIdentifier([]int{2, 5, 29, 15}),
                Critical: true,
                Value:    asn1KeyUsage,
            },
        },
}
    
asn1, err = x509.CreateCertificateRequest(
        rand.Reader,
        csrTemplate,
        privateKey,
    )
   
// Convert asn1 to PEM below
```

Comment: You can use `openssl req` as a debugging tool to print out a CSR in text form. But why do you need keyUsage in a CSR? Key usage is normally designated by the type of key you're buying, not the CSR. For this reason most CAs ignore the keyUsage entirely and assign the one you're entitled to when issuing the certificate.

Comment: I think the CSR needs certSign keyUsage because this CSR contains a basicConstraint (IsCA=true, MaxPathLen=<some int>) to obtain a CA certificate with a constraint on MaxPathLength, and RFC 5280 section 4.2.1.9 says something about keyUsage certSign must be asserted in such cases. When I don't assert certSign in the CSR, GCP CertificateAuthorityService CreateCertificate returns a CA that isn't constrained on MaxPathLen.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also not find a nice short way of adding `KeyUsage` to my CSRs. I looked into golang's code and found [this](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/2580d0e08d5e9f979b943758d3c49877fb2324cb/src/crypto/x509/x509.go#L1257).

I finally ended up extracting following piece of code:

```golang
func marshalKeyUsage(ku x509.KeyUsage) (pkix.Extension, error) {
    ext := pkix.Extension{Id: asn1.ObjectIdentifier{2, 5, 29, 15}, Critical: true}

    var a [2]byte
    a[0] = reverseBitsInAByte(byte(ku))
    a[1] = reverseBitsInAByte(byte(ku >> 8))

    l := 1
    if a[1] != 0 {
        l = 2
    }

    bitString := a[:l]
    var err error
    ext.Value, err = asn1.Marshal(asn1.BitString{Bytes: bitString, BitLength: asn1BitLength(bitString)})
    if err != nil {
        return ext, err
    }
    return ext, nil
}

func reverseBitsInAByte(in byte) byte {
    b1 := in>>4 | in<<4
    b2 := b1>>2&0x33 | b1<<2&0xcc
    b3 := b2>>1&0x55 | b2<<1&0xaa
    return b3
}

func asn1BitLength(bitString []byte) int {
    bitLen := len(bitString) * 8

    for i := range bitString {
        b := bitString[len(bitString)-i-1]

        for bit := uint(0); bit < 8; bit++ {
            if (b>>bit)&1 == 1 {
                return bitLen
            }
            bitLen--
        }
    }

    return 0
}
```

You can use this as:

```golang
keyUsage := x509.KeyUsage(x509.KeyUsageDigitalSignature)
extKeyUsage, err := marshalKeyUsage(keyUsage)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

// add this extension to csr like below

template.ExtraExtensions = []pkix.Extension{extKeyUsage}
```

Comment: Fantastic guidance - thanks for sharing this info